# T.test for each row in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, t-test

I am working with two data frames both with 20502 rows, and I want to preform a `t.test` with the 1st row of one data frame and the 1st of the other data frame and so one until the 20502 row of the two data frames.

ps: I have missing values (NA) in my data frames

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Either you use data frame in the wrong way or you use t test incorrectly.

Comment: I want to to see diferencial methylation, between probes of normal samples and tumor samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're doing correctly, this isn't the typical way to use data.frames - typically, *columns* should stand on their own as variables, not rows, and the host of data.frame tools available makes use of this assumption.  That being said, for data.frames `A` and `B` below...

```
A <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:12,nrow=3,ncol=4))
A
##   V1 V2 V3 V4
## 1  1  4  7 10
## 2  2  5  8 11
## 3  3  6  9 12

B <- as.data.frame(matrix(2:13,nrow=3,ncol=4))
B
##   V1 V2 V3 V4
## 1  2  5  8 11
## 2  3  6  9 12
## 3  4  7 10 13
```

...what you'd like to do is a 2-sample t-test of `c(1,4,7,10)` vs. `c(2,5,8,11)`, etc for each row, all the way down.  You could get there with

```
pvals <- rep(NA, nrow(A))
for(i in 1:nrow(A)) pvals[i] <- t.test(A[i,],B[i,])$p.value
```